# How to get the current user with Signalr?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I tried this, but the user always ends up being null:

```
        ApplicationDbContext db = new Models.ApplicationDbContext();
        var user = db.Users.Find(Context.User.Identity.Name);

        if (user == null)
        {
            caller.displayMessage("Error: User does not exist.");
            return;
        }
```

So, how do I get the current user? I need to get the user's Id and email address.

Comment: Find uses the argument as the key value. I don't think the `Name` property is the key property and hence you never get a result.

Comment: That helps a lot! If you submit your advice as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: This worked for me: `var user = db.Users.Where(x => x.Email == Context.User.Identity.Name).FirstOrDefault();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Find` in EF uses the argument as the key value. I don't think the Name property is the key property and therefore you always get null.